# Rubymine and yarn

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubymine, yarnpkg

I have an error with my RoR project when I try to start it using "Run" (<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>f10</kbd>)

But when I start the server using `rails s` in console, it works.

```
========================================
  Your Yarn packages are out of date!
  Please run `yarn install` to update.
========================================


To disable this check, please add `config.webpacker.check_yarn_integrity = false`
to your Rails development config file (config/environments/development.rb).


yarn check v1.6.0
warning Integrity check: System parameters don't match
error Integrity check failed
error Found 1 errors.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/check for documentation about this command.
```

---

```
# Gemfile.lock
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actioncable (5.2.0)
      actionpack (= 5.2.0)
      nio4r (~> 2.0)
      websocket-driver (>= 0.6.1)
    actionmailer (5.2.0)
      actionpack (= 5.2.0)
      actionview (= 5.2.0)
      activejob (= 5.2.0)
      mail (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
    actionpack (5.2.0)
      actionview (= 5.2.0)
      activesupport (= 5.2.0)
      rack (~> 2.0)
      rack-test (>= 0.6.3)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
    actionview (5.2.0)
      activesupport (= 5.2.0)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      erubi (~> 1.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.3)
    activejob (5.2.0)
      activesupport (= 5.2.0)
      globalid (>= 0.3.6)
    activemodel (5.2.0)
      activesupport (= 5.2.0)
    activerecord (5.2.0)
      activemodel (= 5.2.0)
      activesupport (= 5.2.0)
      arel (>= 9.0)
    activestorage (5.2.0)
      actionpack (= 5.2.0)
      activerecord (= 5.2.0)
      marcel (~> 0.3.1)
    activesupport (5.2.0)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
      i18n (>= 0.7, < 2)
      minitest (~> 5.1)
      tzinfo (~> 1.1)
    addressable (2.5.2)
      public_suffix (>= 2.0.2, < 4.0)
    annotate (2.7.3)
      activerecord (>= 3.2, < 6.0)
      rake (>= 10.4, < 13.0)
    arel (9.0.0)
    babel-source (5.8.35)
    babel-transpiler (0.7.0)
      babel-source (>= 4.0, < 6)
      execjs (~> 2.0)
    bcrypt (3.1.11)
    bindex (0.5.0)
    bootsnap (1.3.0)
      msgpack (~> 1.0)
    builder (3.2.3)
    byebug (10.0.2)
    climate_control (0.2.0)
    coffee-rails (4.2.2)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (>= 4.0.0)
    coffee-script (2.4.1)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.12.2)
    concurrent-ruby (1.0.5)
    connection_pool (2.2.1)
    crass (1.0.4)
    devise (4.4.3)
      bcrypt (~> 3.0)
      orm_adapter (~> 0.1)
      railties (>= 4.1.0, < 6.0)
      responders
      warden (~> 1.2.3)
    econfig (2.0.0)
    erubi (1.7.1)
    execjs (2.7.0)
    exifr (1.3.3)
    ffi (1.9.23)
    font-awesome-rails (4.7.0.4)
      railties (>= 3.2, < 6.0)
    fspath (3.1.0)
    globalid (0.4.1)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
    haml (5.0.4)
      temple (>= 0.8.0)
      tilt
    i18n (1.0.1)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
    image_optim (0.26.1)
      exifr (~> 1.2, >= 1.2.2)
      fspath (~> 3.0)
      image_size (~> 1.5)
      in_threads (~> 1.3)
      progress (~> 3.0, >= 3.0.1)
    image_optim_bin (0.0.7)
    image_size (1.5.0)
    in_threads (1.5.0)
    jbuilder (2.7.0)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
      multi_json (>= 1.2)
    jquery-rails (4.3.3)
      rails-dom-testing (>= 1, < 3)
      railties (>= 4.2.0)
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
    jquery-ui-rails (5.0.5)
      railties (>= 3.2.16)
    kaminari (1.1.1)
      activesupport (>= 4.1.0)
      kaminari-actionview (= 1.1.1)
      kaminari-activerecord (= 1.1.1)
      kaminari-core (= 1.1.1)
    kaminari-actionview (1.1.1)
      actionview
      kaminari-core (= 1.1.1)
    kaminari-activerecord (1.1.1)
      activerecord
      kaminari-core (= 1.1.1)
    kaminari-core (1.1.1)
    launchy (2.4.3)
      addressable (~> 2.3)
    letter_opener (1.6.0)
      launchy (~> 2.2)
    letter_opener_web (1.3.4)
      actionmailer (>= 3.2)
      letter_opener (~> 1.0)
      railties (>= 3.2)
    listen (3.1.5)
      rb-fsevent (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.4)
      rb-inotify (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.7)
      ruby_dep (~> 1.2)
    loofah (2.2.2)
      crass (~> 1.0.2)
      nokogiri (>= 1.5.9)
    mail (2.7.0)
      mini_mime (>= 0.1.1)
    marcel (0.3.2)
      mimemagic (~> 0.3.2)
    method_source (0.9.0)
    mime-types (3.1)
      mime-types-data (~> 3.2015)
    mime-types-data (3.2016.0521)
    mimemagic (0.3.2)
    mini_mime (1.0.0)
    mini_portile2 (2.3.0)
    minitest (5.11.3)
    msgpack (1.2.4)
    multi_json (1.13.1)
    mysql2 (0.5.1)
    nested_form (0.3.2)
    nio4r (2.3.0)
    nokogiri (1.8.2)
      mini_portile2 (~> 2.3.0)
    orm_adapter (0.5.0)
    paperclip (6.0.0)
      activemodel (>= 4.2.0)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
      mime-types
      mimemagic (~> 0.3.0)
      terrapin (~> 0.6.0)
    paperclip-optimizer (2.0.0)
      image_optim (~> 0.19)
      paperclip (>= 3.4)
    possibly (1.0.1)
    progress (3.4.0)
    public_suffix (3.0.2)
    puma (3.11.4)
    rack (2.0.5)
    rack-pjax (1.0.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.5)
      rack (>= 1.1)
    rack-proxy (0.6.4)
      rack
    rack-test (1.0.0)
      rack (>= 1.0, < 3)
    rails (5.2.0)
      actioncable (= 5.2.0)
      actionmailer (= 5.2.0)
      actionpack (= 5.2.0)
      actionview (= 5.2.0)
      activejob (= 5.2.0)
      activemodel (= 5.2.0)
      activerecord (= 5.2.0)
      activestorage (= 5.2.0)
      activesupport (= 5.2.0)
      bundler (>= 1.3.0)
      railties (= 5.2.0)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0.0)
    rails-dom-testing (2.0.3)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
      nokogiri (>= 1.6)
    rails-html-sanitizer (1.0.4)
      loofah (~> 2.2, >= 2.2.2)
    rails-settings-cached (0.6.6)
      rails (>= 4.2.0)
    rails_admin (1.3.0)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      coffee-rails (~> 4.0)
      font-awesome-rails (>= 3.0, < 5)
      haml (>= 4.0, < 6)
      jquery-rails (>= 3.0, < 5)
      jquery-ui-rails (~> 5.0)
      kaminari (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
      nested_form (~> 0.3)
      rack-pjax (>= 0.7)
      rails (>= 4.0, < 6)
      remotipart (~> 1.3)
      sass-rails (>= 4.0, < 6)
    railties (5.2.0)
      actionpack (= 5.2.0)
      activesupport (= 5.2.0)
      method_source
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      thor (>= 0.18.1, < 2.0)
    rake (12.3.1)
    rb-fsevent (0.10.3)
    rb-inotify (0.9.10)
      ffi (>= 0.5.0, < 2)
    react-rails (2.4.4)
      babel-transpiler (>= 0.7.0)
      connection_pool
      execjs
      railties (>= 3.2)
      tilt
    remotipart (1.4.2)
    responders (2.4.0)
      actionpack (>= 4.2.0, < 5.3)
      railties (>= 4.2.0, < 5.3)
    ruby_dep (1.5.0)
    sass (3.5.6)
      sass-listen (~> 4.0.0)
    sass-listen (4.0.0)
      rb-fsevent (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.4)
      rb-inotify (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.7)
    sass-rails (5.0.7)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 6)
      sass (~> 3.1)
      sprockets (>= 2.8, < 4.0)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0, < 4.0)
      tilt (>= 1.1, < 3)
    slim (3.0.9)
      temple (>= 0.7.6, < 0.9)
      tilt (>= 1.3.3, < 2.1)
    spring (2.0.2)
      activesupport (>= 4.2)
    spring-watcher-listen (2.0.1)
      listen (>= 2.7, < 4.0)
      spring (>= 1.2, < 3.0)
    sprockets (3.7.1)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
      rack (> 1, < 3)
    sprockets-rails (3.2.1)
      actionpack (>= 4.0)
      activesupport (>= 4.0)
      sprockets (>= 3.0.0)
    temple (0.8.0)
    terrapin (0.6.0)
      climate_control (>= 0.0.3, < 1.0)
    thor (0.20.0)
    thread_safe (0.3.6)
    tilt (2.0.8)
    turbolinks (5.1.1)
      turbolinks-source (~> 5.1)
    turbolinks-source (5.1.0)
    tzinfo (1.2.5)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
    uglifier (4.1.10)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0, < 3)
    warden (1.2.7)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    web-console (3.6.1)
      actionview (>= 5.0)
      activemodel (>= 5.0)
      bindex (>= 0.4.0)
      railties (>= 5.0)
    webpacker (3.4.3)
      activesupport (>= 4.2)
      rack-proxy (>= 0.6.1)
      railties (>= 4.2)
    websocket-driver (0.7.0)
      websocket-extensions (>= 0.1.0)
    websocket-extensions (0.1.3)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  annotate
  bootsnap (>= 1.1.0)
  byebug
  coffee-rails (~> 4.2)
  devise
  econfig
  image_optim_bin
  jbuilder (~> 2.5)
  letter_opener_web
  listen (>= 3.0.5, < 3.2)
  mysql2 (>= 0.4.4, < 0.6.0)
  paperclip
  paperclip-optimizer
  possibly
  puma (~> 3.11)
  rails (~> 5.2.0)
  rails-settings-cached
  rails_admin (~> 1.3)
  react-rails
  sass-rails (~> 5.0)
  slim
  spring
  spring-watcher-listen (~> 2.0.0)
  turbolinks (~> 5)
  tzinfo-data
  uglifier (>= 1.3.0)
  web-console (>= 3.3.0)
  webpacker

RUBY VERSION
   ruby 2.3.4p301

BUNDLED WITH
   1.16.1
```

System:

```
Ubuntu 17.04
yarn version 1.6.0
Rubymine: try with 2017.3.3 and 2018.1
Gemfile.lock
```

Comment: Have you ran `yarn install` after that?

Comment: yes, sure, but error still present

Comment: I'm facing same error.

Comment: Try `spring stop`. It works for me.

Comment: I am facing the same error. I have been trying all listed fixes for this with no luck. The only way I can run is to disable the check by adding config.webpacker.check_yarn_integrity = false to development.rb. But this is not a solution, just a work around.

Answer (score 2):

try this as a solution

```
spring stop
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar issue.  However, when I ran `sudo yarn install` I was getting warnings about wrong version of node.

In the end I tracked it down to there existing an old version of node in `/usr/local/bin`.  Removing that fixed the problem for me.  `sudo yarn install` then reported that everything was up-to-date.

Comment: I had the same problem as you, thanks for helping me solve it! I created a self-contained Q&A to handle our case: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59018953/3287963