# RubyMine's run config results in error that "Yarn requires Node.js 4.0" on Ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, rubymine

On my Elementary OS machine (an Ubuntu-based OS), after creating a new Ruby on Rails project with `rails new yarntest` and loading it in RubyMine, I could not launch it with RubyMine's "Development: yarntest" run configuration. The output was:

```
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 6.0.1 application starting in development 
=> Run `rails server --help` for more startup options
Yarn requires Node.js 4.0 or higher to be installed.


========================================
  Your Yarn packages are out of date!
  Please run `yarn install --check-files` to update.
========================================


To disable this check, please change `check_yarn_integrity`
to `false` in your webpacker config file (config/webpacker.yml).
```

However, running `rails server` in the console worked.

I tried [reinstalling Yarn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53441422/3287963), but it still did not work.

I could only [disable the Yarn integrity check in the Ruby on Rails config](https://github.com/rails/webpacker/issues/1374#issuecomment-463204428) as stated in the error message ([deleting the `yarn.lock`](https://github.com/rails/webpacker/issues/1374#issuecomment-546607818) also appeared to work, but is surely wrong). Similarly, I did not want to track down and remove the different Yarn version, as [suggested on another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57387534/3287963), since the issue was with RubyMine.

Comment: just to be sure, does it mean that running rails server manually in the Terminal doesn't show that message? (in case you don't use sudo)

Comment: Exactly. Running the command in the terminal without sudo works fine.

Comment: Does it behave the same way in case you launch RubyMine from the terminal where it works?

Comment: Yes, launching Ruby Mine from the terminal does solve the issue. Do you know of a way to fix this permanently?

Comment: There's a similar request on the tracker with possible workarounds, please take a look: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-7589

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rubymine and yarn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50078826/rubymine-and-yarn)

Comment: @KickButtowski As I mentioned in a comment on an answer for that question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50078826/rubymine-and-yarn#comment104283799_57387534), this Q&A is supposed to cover another error message. Olivia helped me understand the underlying issues, which are not covered in that question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came across an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57387534/3287963) on [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50078826/3287963) that mentioned this error message when running `sudo yarn install` (i. e. in sudo mode). I tried running `sudo yarn install` and could finally reproduce the error message outside of RubyMine's run config. Apparently, when running in sudo mode, the `yarn` binary was outdated.

The solution is therefore to point RubyMine to the correct `yarn` binary.

The easiest way to do that is to launch RubyMine from the terminal with `rubymine`, as [pointed out by Olivia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59018952/ruby-mines-run-config-results-in-error-that-yarn-requires-node-js-4-0-on-ubun?noredirect=1#comment104341528_59018952). See the related [JetBrains ticket](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-7589).

Comment: Workaround 1: make required variables available in a login shell (i.e. for Bash, move them from .bashrc to .bash_profile or .profile), then restart X session (logout/login).
Workaround 2: run IDE from a terminal
Workaround 3: edit IDE desktop launcher and set command to /bin/bash -l -i -c  "/path/to/webstorm.sh"